# Moderator messages not showing on Pets site

Tags: bug, global-inbox

The last mod message I've seen is for December 6th, but there's been activity on the meta site since then with no notification in the diamond on the header bar. It's either specific to the Pets site, or to the beta sites, as I don't see this behavior on the Photography site where I also moderate.

Comment: Well, certainly there's no answer there to be found...